# Comments encourage discussion threads

Tags: discussion, comments

I've been answering questions on SO fairly intensively for about 6 months now so my sample is admittedly very small, but one thing I noticed is that comments asking for clarification about a question are almost always answered by the OP with another comment, rarely by improving the question. I think this is detrimental to the quality of questions asked on SO. If this has been discussed on MSO already (I couldn't find anything), please consider reading the suggestion below in case it is still relevant.

My thinking is that an *answerable* question does not need commenting upon (except to flag but that is not relevant to this discussion); as soon as all the required info is in the question and understandable, answers can come forth. So comments should really only be for potential answerers to indicate to the OP what info is missing or unclear from the question; comment should not be for the OP to add the missing info. The OP should address the question comments by editing their question, not by creating another comment. I thought the reason for not having threaded comments on SO is that SO is *not* a discussion forum so discourage long sequences of comment/clarification/comment/clarification/etc, like you see in discussion forums -- such use of comments is a misuse of SO comment system.

So it seems to me that the only thing the OP should use the comment system for is to say `@commenterName Updated`. One way to encourage this might be to constrain comments by OP to their *own* question, *for OP below a certain rep* (i.e. while they are "learning the ropes", so below say a couple hundred points). It would work like this:

1. below MIN_REP, OP can't add more than 20-25 characters after the `@name` in a comment to their own question,
2. SO makes their comment text *default* to `@who I updated my question`: this sends the OP a clear message what comments are for and would force OP to clean up their question. The system could refuse to send comment if the "@who" part of the default comment has not been edited.

The reverse would apply for answers: OP is not constrained in their comments to answers (except for the current 500 char limit), but answerer with less than MIN_REP must use fewer than 25 chars after the `@who` in comments to their own answer.

So it would look like this:

```
Question by OP: 
  blablabla
  blablabla
  blablabla

  Comment by @who1: blablabla                 (< 500 chars)
  Comment by OP:    @who1 Updated my question (< 25 chars)
  Comment by @who2: blablabla                 (< 500 chars)
  Comment by OP:    @who2 Updated my question (< 25 chars)
  Comment by @who1: blablabla                 (< 500 chars)
  Comment by OP:    @who1 Updated my question (< 25 chars)

Answer 1 by who2: 
  blablabla
  blablabla
  blablabla

  Comment by OP:   blablabla               (< 500 chars)
  Comment by who2: @OP Updated my answer   (< 25 chars)
  Comment by who1: blablabla               (< 500 chars)
  Comment by OP:   blablabla               (< 500 chars)
```

The above does *not* assume that comment always requires editing of the question/answer to address: The OP can ignore comment (not required to edit). There is also no assumption that comment is always correct: if one person made a comment that is incorrect, others probably think same, so it is useful to address the issue as part of the question (as I just did).

Comment: So the number of characters allowed in comments should be context-sensitive?  Too much of AI.

Comment: Assumes that the comment is always correct and requires editing of the question/answer to address.  That is certainly not always the case.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Updated.

Comment: Ok, you made me laugh.  But I'm still unconvinced.  To make it convincing, edit the question in such a way that the response to my comment isn't merely tacked onto the end.  In fact, the piece that you've added makes a statement that is not supported by what comes before it.

Comment: For some reason, i thought that the asker of a question was already notified when an answer changes.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work

Answer (score 5):

I oppose the suggestion here, for a very simple reason.

It is not rare that I get a comment on an answer that does not call for an edit to the answer but *still* calls for *some sort* of response. Sometimes I have to write a long comment to explain to the OP that the question they've just asked in a comment to my answer really is a *new* question and should be posted to SO as such (instead of me editing my answer). Or sometimes the off-topic concern is readily answerable in a long comment and does not call for a new question. With this proposal, I'd have to edit my answer to respond to a concern that is really off-topic relative to the original question.

Now, granted that *I'm* probably above the `MIN_REP` threshold. (I'd sure hope so). Still, this would essentially be training people who don't have the required reputation that if they want to answer off-topic concerns *at all* they should do it in the body of their answer instead of doing it in a comment. (Or post an answer in a dozen fragmented comments, I suppose.) However, editorial practices on SO are such that such noise should not be included in posts in the first place and should be removed from posts when encountered. So while they might acquire the good habit of editing into their post what should be there, **they might just as well acquire the bad habit of editing into their post what should not be there.**

I've talked about off-topic concerns above but I could just as well have talked about tangential concerns. Or cases where one person who happens to read the question and the answer does not understand something that the dozens of other folks understand and needs a tailored clarification.

I've focused on answers because I answer much more than I ask but I don't see a material difference between questions and answers when it comes to this suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Is the above a question that needs answering?  It's hard enough to communicate on the internet and you want to raise the difficulty level by character counting?

I wish the comments allowed more formatting.  Ideally, the emphasis should be on letting people learn from each other and getting to an answer -- which may take some back & forth so that everyone is on the same page.  I often find that I don't want a simple answer and often would prefer the option to elaborate more.

Another Q I read just before looking at this was about closing out or having questioner's remove questions that are too trivial.  By cutting down on ability to 'converse' about the problem, you might be cutting off a completely different line of how to answer the question and certainly are going to end up with more questions that are not well fleshed out or well thought through.

I'm of the opinion that if people *want* conversations, about the topic, then maybe communication should be allowed that deliberation and question depth can be developed.

Also, I'm of the belief that if people continue to seek answers in these communities, then their questions will improve to make trivial comments 'unnecessary' -- but if the question development doesn't happen, then learning what people want to know and how to better ask questions won't happen, or at least will be more delayed.

Comment: some good points there